# standardJournalName method from InventJournalName

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In InventJournalName table there is JournalNameId column and JournalType.

Using:

```
InventJournalNameId inventJournalName;

inventJournalName = InventJournalName::standardJournalName(InventJournalType::Movement);
```

I am indeed able to get a JournalNameId of type Movement from the InventJournalName table. To be more concise, the first one.

With the debugger I got to this point :

```
public static InventParameters find(boolean _forupdate = false)
{
   InventParameters parameter;

   if (_forupdate)
   {
      parameter.selectForUpdate(_forupdate);
   }

   select firstonly parameter
      index Key
      where parameter.Key == 0;

   if (!parameter && !parameter.isTmp())
   {
      Company::createParameter(parameter);
      PrintMgmt::createDefaultData(PrintMgmtHierarchyType::Invent);
   }

  return parameter;
}
```

To be honest, I can't really understand what's the role of the InventParameters table.

It's clear that:

```
select firstonly parameter
   index Key
   where parameter.Key == 0;
```

will return what I need but what's the mechanism behind the scenes?

Is there any difference between the above way and:

```
select firstOnly inventJournalName
where inventJournalName.JournalType ==
InventJournalType::Movement;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have a parameter is because you should be able to define a standard journal name regardless of how many journal names you have in the `InventJournalName` table.

You can have multiple journal names in that table for the same journal type, as long as they don't have the same name.

If you have 2 names of type movement this code

```
select firstOnly inventJournalName
where inventJournalName.JournalType ==
InventJournalType::Movement;
```

would basically return a random record (if there is no order by there is no guarantee which will be first).

This on the other hand

```
select firstonly parameter
   index Key
   where parameter.Key == 0;
```

Will return what's in your parameter table and is deterministic.

If you were wondering why the `where parameter.key == 0` is for. That's because of how AX's caching mechanism works. All parameter tables are set to `entiretablecache=yes` but records are only retrieved from cache if the select is on the primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it and found the form on Inventory Management > Setup > Inventory and warehouse management parameters where those parameters are set.